# Retrofit Square Brackets Query Parameters

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I have the following GET URL that requires multiple parameters:

```
https://www.games.com/game?filter[condition][path]=season&filter[condition][value]=Season1&page[limit]=1&page[offset]=0
```

However, I can't find a way to represent this parametrized call using Retrofit because it's using Square Brackets.

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work, since Retrofit cannot recognize those parameters.

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET("game")
Call<FunctionsResponse> getAllGames(
        @Query("filter[condition][path]") String conditionFilter,
        @Query("filter[condition][value]") String conditionValue,
        @Query("page[limit]") String pageLimit,
        @Query("page[offset]") String pageOffset
);
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know if you still got error

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET("game")
Call<FunctionsResponse> getAllGames(
        @Query("filter%5Bcondition%5D%5Bpath%5D") String conditionFilter,
        @Query("filter%5Bcondition%5D%5Bvalue%5D") String conditionValue,
        @Query("page%5Blimit%5D") String pageLimit,
        @Query("page%5Boffset%5D") String pageOffset
);
```

In this code, the square brackets [ and ] are encoded as %5B and %5D, respectively, using URL encoding. Retrofit will properly encode the query parameters with square brackets and include them in the request URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **@QueryMap** annotation instead of individual **@Query** annotations.

Here is how you can achieve it:

```
Map<String, String> queryMap = new HashMap<>();
queryMap.put("filter[condition][path]", "season");
queryMap.put("filter[condition][value]", "Season1");
queryMap.put("page[limit]", "1");
queryMap.put("page[offset]", "0");
Call<FunctionsResponse> call = yourApiService.getAllGames(queryMap);
```